# why different Mandelbrot zooming values yields same results?

Tags: graphics, fractals, mandelbrot

what gives one the ability to define how deep the zooming process would be?
what i mean is that i tried earlier to run mandelbrot set with 200 iteration and then compared the results with a 1000 iterations run. the results were kinda surprising because i got the same zooming level.the iterations were constant the entire process and the mandelbrot set was defined with 512X512 pixels constant.  what should i change in order to get a deeper zooming level?
thanks!

edit : i would also like to mention that from nice looking picture, after i get to the 2nd-3rd level of mandelbrot the entire set is viewed as a giant pixel. why is that?

2d edit : after an extensive research i've just noticed that what makes the entire set to look like a big pixel is because all points get same iterations count,in my case they are all 60...

Comment: This would be a whole lot easier to discuss if you'd share your iteration code, so we're using the same terms - because I'm not even sure what you mean by "level[s] of mandelbrot".

Answer (score 2):

This may be too abstract, or too concrete, or incomprehensible. Like I said in the comment, it would be easier to discuss with your code at hand.

If you mean what I think you mean by zooming, you'd change the boundaries of `c` (in the formula `z[n+1] = z[n]^2 + c`).

To explain, the full Mandelbrot set is contained within a circle with radius 2 around a center `[0;0]`. The `c` in the formula is a complex number, i.e. `[r;i]` (real;imaginary), which, on the computer screen, corresponds to `x` and `y`.

In other words, if we place that radius 2 circle so that it is exactly contained within our image, then `[-2;2]` will be the upper left corner of our image, and `[2;-2]` is the lower right corner.

We then take each point of our image, calculate what its pixel coordinates `[x;y]` correspond to in terms of the smaller, "actual" coordinate system `[r;i]`. Then we have our `c` and can send it through our iterations.

So, to "zoom", you'd pick other boundaries `[r;i]` than the full `[-2;2]`,`[2:-2]`, e.g. `[-1;1]`,`[1:-1]`.

With 512x512 pixels, and an "actual" coordinate system that's now 2 by 2, that would mean each pixel corresponds to 2/512 units of the "actual" coordinate system. So your first `r` value would be -1, the next would be `-1 + 2/512 = -0.99609375` etc.

The number of iterations only decide how accurate your rendering will be. Generally, the further you "zoom" in, the more accurate they'll *need* to be, so the more iterations you'll need in order to capture the details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but i think i managed to fix the problem. what actually happened was that i represented my points as float... so after few "Zooms" i got zero precision problems. but now im facing a new problem where CUDA says  Double is not supported. Demoting to float. im using G105M

Comment: @igalk, exactly! For deep zoom you need arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: @igalk "few" zooms shouldn't exceed a single precision float's limits :-) although I admit Float is imprecise by default, 1.8 -1 is not equal to 1.7.